# Survival's function

Tags: calculus

I know that function of survival is:

$S(t) = 1- F(t) = P [ T > t ]$

But, how I can show that $E[ T ] = \int_0^\infty S(t) dt $ ?

Could someone help me ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $T$ is valid on $[0,\infty)$ and integrate by parts letting
$u = 1-F_t$ (so $du = -f_t dt$) and $dv = dt$ (so $v=t$):
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^\infty (1-F_t)dt &= \int udv = uv - \int vdu \\
   &= \left.t(1-F_t)\right|_0^\infty + \int_0^\infty t f_t dt \\
   &= 0 + \mathbb{E}[T]
\end{split}
$$

Comment: @rgl4 no problem. Make sure to note that you need to prove that $t \cdot S_t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$ (it is non-trivial because the limit takes the shape of $0 \cdot \infty$)

Comment: if I do: 

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} t(1-F_t) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{t}{\frac{1}{1-F_t}} = (by L'Hôpital) = \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac{(1-F_t)^2}{f_t} = 0$ (because $F(\infty) = 1$ and $f(t)$ is limited)

It is correct?

Comment: @rgl4 not so sure, could be $f_t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$, the question is, how fast...